# Ports 49918 is already in use

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am running login page is hosted on port 49918, I can not use another port. App runs on other range of ports like 4200.

try installing angular cli globally

```
netstat -ano | findStr :49918
```

---

```
Dev: {
    authority: 'https://dev-im.com',
    client_id: 'APC',
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/oidclogin',
    silent_redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/oidcrenew',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/oidclogout',
    response_type: 'code id_token token',
    scope: 'openid email profile api1 offline_access',
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    monitorSession: true
  }
```

my angular app must run locally after login
[image]

Comment: I created new angular app. when i run `ng serve --o --port 49918`. It give me this error. **listen EACCES: permission denied **127.0.0.1:49918
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:49918
    at _Server.setupListenHandle_ [as _listen2] (net.js:1253:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1451:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things in that situation:

Either you want to set another port : `ng serve --o  --port 1234`

OR

you can do this:

Open Command Prompt and type: `netstat -a -o -n`

Find the PID of the process that you want to kill.

Type: `taskkill /F /PID 49918`

This one **49918** - is the PID for the process that we want to kill and then start again. check the attached file.

[image]

Comment: it is already stated in question that Abrar cannot use another port and `netstat -a -o -n` also returned empty result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ng serve`, angular live development server is listening on localhost: 4200 and you can open browser on  [http://localhost:4200/](http://%20http://localhost:4200/)

if you want to open it automatically you can use `ng serve --o`.

& if you want to change the port you can use `ng serve --o  --port 4220` open with  [http://localhost:4220/](http://%20http://localhost:4220/)

you can replace `4220`with your not using port.

Answer (score 0):

Your Angular app will work well even if the global Angular CLI version is higher than the local version of your Angular app.

Yes, it is difficult to find the already dead process which is listening to the ports in windows, but it is not impossible.

You can use the Windows Resource Manager to find out this listening port.

`Start >> All Programs >> Accessories >> System Tools >> Resource Monitor`

[image]

or

Run `(Win + r)` type `resmon.exe` then press `Enter`

Look for Network Tab

Search for your port number and find its PID.

Kill the process with that PID using Task Manager or using below command

`taskkill /F /PID pid_number`

That's it!

Now try running your angular app again.

Comment: Port 49918 is not available in resmon.exe. I also download currports software. There is no port 49918 for me to kill PID.